# Netbeans: Can I change the way my project is displayed in the Projects tab?

Tags: android, maven, netbeans, maven-archetype

So, as you know, the Projects tab of Netbeans displays your project in a different structure than the real file system structure (as you see in the Files tab).

My problem is, I'm creating an Android project from a Maven archetype and Netbeans doesn't seem to know what it's doing in the Projects tab for this particular case. The "res" folder is missing, the "gen" folder (which I'd rather hide) is showing and there's another useless "generated assets" folder.

Note: The file structure was generated right. The problem is only the Projects view.

Edit:
This is the pom.xml generated when I use the "android-quickstart" archetype, which group id is "de.akquinet.android.archetypes"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>uk.frequency</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version> 4.1.1.4
        </platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.6.0</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Note: On my latest attempt, it didn't create "gen" folders, but still no "res" either.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the pom.xml.

BTW: IIRC NB only shows generated sources in the project view when they match the maven standard convention.

Comment: pom.xml added. tnx for the answer. by maven standard convention you mean the folder structure? as in if I changed the folder names they would be hidden?

Comment: Ok. Nothing special in your pom.xml. <br>
```target/generated-sources/XXX``` will be supported. See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=191864